# Using Razor and Spark simultaineously in ASP.NET MVC 2 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, spark-view-engine

How to use certain view engine for certain controller?

Now my project using MVC2 + Spark view engine. I want to migrate to Razor view engine. Project so big, and I want to do this step-by-step.

Comment: I would recommend branching your code and migrating all your views in one go.

I personally would never try to support multiple rendering engines in a single instance of a production app

Comment: I'm do not see any problem. New functional implements using Razor, and old rewriting step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to run both view engines simultaneously. Since you're currently using Spark you probably have an entry in your global.asax that clears the current view engines and adds in the Spark engine. Something like:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ...);
```

MVC is designed to use FindView and FindPartial (part of the ViewEngine interface) to find the correct view for an action, and if it can't find one for the first view engine in the list, it moves on to the next viewengine and looks for its appropriate views, until there aren't any other view engines to try.

It's up to you whether it looks for Razor Views first and then falls back to Spark, or the other way round, so make sure you place the ViewEngines in the correct order. Or to have the default engines, you can delete the ViewEngines.EnginesClear() line and make Spark first by using ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, ...)

If that's not clear then paste in the global.asax code around the Spark bit and I can try to help you more.